# Singular Value Decomposition on covariance matrix for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, covariance, svd

Suppose $x$ is MVN($0_n$, $I_n$), how to find $a$ and $B$ such that $a+Bx$ is MVN($\mu$, $\Sigma$)?

Here is what I try:

$a$ is easy to find: $$a = \mu$$

for B:

$$Cov(Bx) = BI_nB^T = \Sigma$$

The problem is to find matrix $B$ using SVD.

Anyone help with how to perform the SVD here?

Thanks!

Comment: $B$ doesn't have to be orthogonal.  You could use a "Cholesky decomposition"  $L\,L^T = \Sigma$ of the covariance matrix, say.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, what if I want to use SVD to get the matrix $B$? Any help, please

Comment: You cannot in general hope that $B I_n B^T = B B^T = \Sigma$, because $\Sigma$ might not have determinant 1.  Instead, focus on what the SVD does deliver: a factorization $U \Delta U^T = \Sigma$,...

Comment: Ahh, I see. Start SVD on $\Sigma$ instead of focusing on $B$? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Sigma = UDU'$ is the SVD decomposition of a positive definite matrix $\Sigma$. Then $a = \mu$ and $B = U D^{1/2}$.

When $\Sigma$ is only semi-positive definite, then $\Sigma = UDV'$, possibly with  $V \neq U$, but can still take $B = U D^{1/2}$.

Alternatively you can perform the pivoted Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$:
$$\Sigma = (PL) \times (PL)'$$
where $L$ is lower triangular, and $P$ is a permutation matrix. Then $B = PL$.

Comment: I see, I overthink the problem a little bit. Thank you for the answer!